# WPF using command and event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, event-handling

I have a save button and I want to use the MVVM design pattern, but I need to close the window once the save has been done, I looked a little on the web and saw that this is a lot of work, so i decided to make the window.close() on the code behind and all the saving logic on the view model.

How can I implement a button with a command binding and also an event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195267/983064) which worked pretty well for me. You can pass the window itself as a command parameter and then use it in the viewmodel to close it.

Relevant XAML from that answer:

```
Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TestWindow}"
```

Relevant ViewModel command handler from the same answer:

```
private void CloseWindow(Window window)
{
    if (window != null)
    {
       window.Close();
    }
}
```

You'll obviously also need to expose a command to bind to, in this case called `CloseWindowCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the two in the button xaml like so:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Click="Button_click"/>
```