# MVVM Light - Get Window instance to set icon after PropertyChange

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I want to change the .ico depending on which Checkbox is checked:

```
        <MenuItem Header="_Online" Command="{Binding SetStatusOnlineCommand}"  />
        <MenuItem Header="_Away" Command="{Binding SetStatusAwayCommand}" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Offline" Command="{Binding SetStatusOfflineCommand}" />
```

Since I am using MVVM Light and it's SimpleIoC I don't know how to achieve this.

My ViewModel doesn't know the Window it's representing, and thus I can't change the Icon of the Window. My Window get's it DataContext inside XAML via the localter:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="MainPanel"  DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

I wanted to create a PropertyChangeEvent inside my ViewModel. The Window registers to this event, but since I am instanciating via the Locator inside my XAML, I don't have access to it from my Window, or am I wrong?!

I could use OnChange-Events ... but then I will break the MVVM pattern. Does anyone have a nice idea ho to achieve this?!

Comment: Looks like a perfect use case for publish-subscriber pattern: Your Command(s) send a Message; your Windows subscribes to this messages and acts accordingly.

Comment: I'd bind the window's `Icon` property to a `Status` property in the view-model, with a converter or data-trigger to select the appropriate icon based on the value of that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the window as a command parameter:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Online" Command="{Binding SetStatusOnlineCommand}"
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=YourWindowName}" />
```

Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195267/5147720

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect!