# MVVM: Is code-behind evil or just pragmatic?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, code-behind

Imagine you want a `Save & Close` and a `Cancel & Close` button on your fancy WPF MVVM window?

How would you go about it? MVVM dictates that you bind the button to an `ICommand` and inversion of control dictates that your `View` may know your `ViewModel` but not the other way around.

Poking around the net I found a solution that has a `ViewModel` closing event to which the `View` subscribes to like this:

```
private void OnLoaded(Object sender
    , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IFilterViewModel viewModel = (IFilterViewModel)DataContext;
    viewModel.Closing += OnViewModelClosing;
}

private void OnViewModelClosing(Object sender
    , EventArgs<Result> e)
{
    IFilterViewModel viewModel = (IFilterViewModel)DataContext;
    viewModel.Closing -= OnViewModelClosing;
    DialogResult = (e.Value == Result.OK) ? true : false;
    Close();
}
```

But that is code-behind mixed in with my so far very well designed MVVM.

Another problem would be showing a licensing problem message box upon showing the main window. Again I could use the `Window`.`Loaded` event like I did above, but that's also breaking MVVM, is it not?

Is there a clean way or should one be pragmatical instead of pedantic in these cases?

Comment: "MVVM dictates that you bind the button to an ICommand" Does it? You could still add a Click handler without breaking anything. Be pragmatic.

Comment: mvvm != no codebehind. On the other hand, the pattern serves us, we do not serve the pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, create an interface that contains only the `Close` method:

```
interface IClosable
{
    void Close();
}
```

Next, make your window implement `IClosable`:

```
class MyWindow : Window, IClosable
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then let the view pass itself as `IClosable` as command parameter to the view model:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

And lastly, the command calls `Close`:

```
CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand<IClosable>( view => view.Close() );
```

And what have we now?

- we have a button that closes the window
- we have no code in code-behind *except* `, IClosable`
- the view model knows nothing about the view, it just gets an arbitrary object that can be closed
- the command can easily be unit tested

Comment: But what if the user closes the windows in anther way, e.g. using the OS's window manger..... (X in corner of window on NT.)

Comment: That's not part of the original question, but it would be done through an `EventTrigger` using an `InvokeCommandAction` and then the same command...

Comment: Or just mark the button as the close button in the markup and put a simple one line event handler in the code behind with the VM exposing a Close() method then view can call.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong or right with using code behind, this is mainly opinion based and depends on your preference.

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195267/3090249) shows how to close a window using an MVVM design pattern without code behind.

```
<Button Name="btnLogin" IsDefault="True" Content="Login" Command="{Binding ShowLoginCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LoginWindow}"/> 
<!-- the CommandParameter should bind to your window, either by name or relative or what way you choose, this will allow you to hold the window object and call window.Close() -->
```

basically you pass the window as a parameter to the command. IMO your viewmodel shouldn't be aware of the control, so this version is not that good. I would pass a `Func<object>`/ some interface to the viewmodel for closing the window using dependency injection.

Comment: Can you give me a code snippet on how to write the XAML that would take the `Window`.`Close()' method as a command parameter?

Comment: added the main part, look at the example for a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some toolkits e.g. MVVMLight has EventToCommand, which allows you to bind command to events. I generally try my best to limit logic in View, as it's harder to test it.

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

...

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
     <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding YourCommandInVM}"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks, that would help with the problem of the message box. But an entire toolkit dependency for one feature is a heavy price to pay. :-(

Comment: @Dee J. Doena Completelly understand, but 1) it's got other usefull features too 2) what it's doing is not magic, and I think it's open source so you could take a look at the source code and see what's the hard way of doing that :)

Comment: You have just moved hard to test code from your view.cs into your markup.    The markup is just as likely (if not more) to be damaged by a merge etc then the code behind is.

Comment: @Ian what do you mean by that? I have moved code (body of event handler) from view to view model. Are you suggesting that I should test the binding? It's strongly typed, what do you want to test there? The only thing you can mess up is event name.

Comment: Its not as if you would messed up the "body of event handler" without trying, and the "strong typing" in the markup is not check at compile time, so does not show an error until you use that bit of the UI.

Comment: I have seen far too many merges of markup between branches go wrong and not get detected by unit tests or the build sever, to leave me with much trust in markup.   Most merges that go wrong of cs code result in the build failing.

Comment: @Ian can you please come up with an example of what can go wrong with my markup ? Just want to check if my current tools would detect that, because I haven't had such problems that you describe

Comment: Most likely you are not working with lots of other developers on a large project when the same mark-up get edited by people in different teams on different source control branches, and then the branches merged by yet anther person.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use a work-around.

Assumes u have a `view` "MainWindow" and a `viewmodel` "MainWindowVM".

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    private MainWindow mainWindow;
    public delegate void EventWithoudArg();
    public event EventWithoudArg Closed;

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Closed += MainWindow_Closed;
        mainWindow.DataContext = this;
        mainWindow.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        mainWindow.Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded()
    {
        //your code
    }

    private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //your code
    }

    private void MainWindow_Closed()
    {
        Closed?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Here I store my view in a private variable so you can access it if you need it. It breaks a bit the MVVM.
In my viewmodel, I create a new `view` and show it.
Here I also capture the closing event of the `view` an pass it to an own event.
You can also add a method to the `.Loaded` and `.Closing` events of your `view`.

In App.xaml.cs you just have to create a new `viewmodel` object.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        MainWindowVM mainWindowVM = new MainWindowVM();
        mainWindowVM.Closed += Mwvm_Close;
    }

    private void Mwvm_Close()
    {
        this.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

I create a new `viewmodel` object and capture it own close-event and bind it to the shutdown method of the App.

Answer (score 0):

Your description indicates that the view model is some kind of a document view. If that's correct then I would leave `Save, Close, etc.` to be handled by the document container e.g. the application or the main window, because these commands are on a level above the document in the same way as copy/paste are on the application level. In fact `ApplicationCommands` has predefined commands for both Save and Close which indicates a certain approach from the authors of the framework.