# Navigate to view in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a Method in MainWindowViewModel.cs to navigate the view by passing viewname as a parameter.

Navigation Method(By Relay Command)

```
public void onNav(string destination)
{
    switch (destination)
    {
        case "study":
            CurrentViewModel = new StudyViewModel();
            break;
        case "capture":
            CurrentViewModel = new ImageCaptureViewModel();
            break;
        case "register":
            CurrentViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
            break;
        case "editing":
            CurrentViewModel = new ImageEditingViewModel();
            break;
        default:
            CurrentViewModel = new ImageCaptureViewModel();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I am calling from `RegisterViewModel` this method is triggered and `CurrentViewModel` values updated. But the corresponding View is not showing in the Window.

```
var mainModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
mainModel.OnNav("study");
```

It is updating ViewModel but not updating View. How to fix it.

Comment: You're creating a new instane of MainWindowViewModel and call the OnNav-Method there. I guess that this is not the same instance as your MainWindowView is bound to

Comment: @Tomtom I dont no how to do this. What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

WPF has a little difference to UWP. You don't update the existed view, you close the current view and open a new windows. In your case:
Consider the `StudyViewModel` is the name of the ViewModel and `Study` is the name of the View.

```
public void onNav(string destination)
{
    switch (destination)
    {
        case "study":
            Study window = new Study();
            break;
        ...
        default:
            ImageCapture window = new ImageCapture();
            break;
    }

    //Show the window
    window.Show();
}
```

This is not relate to your question but you need to close the current window before open a new window in MVVM way, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172462/close-window-from-viewmodel).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have fixed this problem using single instance. Instead creating object to MainViewModel, i am getting instance of that ViewModel which already created. Like

var instance=MainWindowViewModel.GetInstance();

GetInstance() will return the instance of the MainWindowViewModel which created already.